# Woocommerce 504 on Product with Six attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm hoping somebody can help me, I've got a woocommerce install that 504 errors when adding a product with six attributes to the cart. There is one 'catchall' variation set up for the product. I have disabled all plugins and reverted to the storefront theme and still experience the same issue, it appears to be directly related to a very slow SQL query that is being run.

The query appears to be selecting the post ID where the meta values for the attribute match the selected attributes which in this case is suboptimal as there are 70k entries in the post_meta table and hundreds in the post table. This query does not complete in a reasonable timeframe and is called more than once so kills off the SQL server. Personally I was able to rewrite the query to be much faster in mysql workbench but I can't figure out where it's being generated. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT   wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_workbee-size-drive' )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt3.post_id AND mt3.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_extrusion-colour' )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt4 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt4.post_id )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt5 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt5.post_id AND mt5.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_router' )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt6 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt6.post_id )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt7 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt7.post_id AND mt7.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_dust-shoe' )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt8 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt8.post_id )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt9 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt9.post_id AND mt9.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_cam-software' )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt10 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt10.post_id )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt11 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt11.post_id AND mt11.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_connectivity' ) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_parent = 2603  AND ( 
 ( 
   ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_workbee-size-drive' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IN ('','') ) 
   OR 
   mt1.post_id IS NULL
 ) 
 AND 
 ( 
   ( mt2.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_extrusion-colour' AND mt2.meta_value IN ('','') ) 
   OR 
   mt3.post_id IS NULL
 ) 
 AND 
 ( 
   ( mt4.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_router' AND mt4.meta_value IN ('','') ) 
   OR 
   mt5.post_id IS NULL
 ) 
 AND 
 ( 
   ( mt6.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_dust-shoe' AND mt6.meta_value IN ('','') ) 
   OR 
   mt7.post_id IS NULL
 ) 
 AND 
 ( 
   ( mt8.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_cam-software' AND mt8.meta_value IN ('','') ) 
   OR 
   mt9.post_id IS NULL
 ) 
 AND 
 ( 
   ( mt10.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_connectivity' AND mt10.meta_value IN ('','') ) 
   OR 
   mt11.post_id IS NULL
 )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product_variation' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: Did you solve this? Having the same problem

Comment: Hi, this one turned out to be a discounts plugin that was causing the issue. We disabled that and ensured that there were always variations created for the product so that it didn't need to go looking to find the variation from the post parent and selected attributes. It wasn't an ideal fix but it did get the site up and running without any further issues.